# ¿Cómo optimizar la aplicación de rank a una matriz?

Tags: r, optimización

Me encuentro calculando los patrones de permutación de las filas de una matriz en `R` usando la función `rank`. Un patrón de permutación asigna un numero entre 1 y la longitud del vector, digamos `D`, para cada numero del vector, asignando uno a la posición donde se encuentra el minimo, 2 a la posición del siguiente numero mayor al mínimo y así sucesivamente. A continuación presento mi código:

```
A_pasted<-t(apply(A,1, rank)) #aplica la funcion rank a cada vector fila de la matriz
Z_concat<-apply(A_pasted, 1,paste0, collapse="_") #concatena los valores obtenidos por fila para permitir hacer la compacación
```

Donde `A` es la matriz que quiero operar. Mi principal problema es que, aunque la primera linea del código toma alrededor de 10 segundos por iteración, debo replicar esta función varios cientos de miles de veces, por lo que necesito un código más rápido que me permita hacer lo mismo. También intenté usando `parLapply`pero inclusive toma más tiempo.

Hay alguna forma de resolver el problema?

Comment: please translate your question, this is the spanish version of SO, otherwise it will be closed

Comment: Hi, Jorge! This site is purely in Spanish, consider translating your question into Spanish or migrating it to the site in English [so].

Comment: Traducido! Pensé que estaba en la página en ingles :D

Comment: Hola Jorge, por curiosidad, ¿Qué tipo de datos tendría tu matriz A? y ¿Qué dimensiones tiene?. Cuando dices replicar la función varios cientos miles de veces a que te refieres, ¿a que debes aplicarla a tantas matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Respuesta corta.

Usando `data.table::frank()`

## Respuesta larga

La librería `data.table` tiene algunas funciones comunes de R base en versiones rápidas. Para `rank()` está `frank()`, *fast* rank.
Hice una prueba con datos sintéticos y simples y en este caso reduce más del 40% el tiempo de ejecución, todo lo demás igual.

```
# Preparo los datos.
set.seed(123)
matrix(sample(1:1000000, 500000, replace =TRUE), ncol=100) -> test  #Replace TRUE para que haya empates.

# Valido que den el mismo output. 
all.equal(apply(test, 2, rank), apply(test, 2, data.table::frank))  #TRUE: con los argumentos por defecto hacen lo mismo

library(microbenchmark)

bencho_1core <- microbenchmark(
  apply(test, 2, rank) -> con_rank,
  apply(test, 2, data.table::frank) -> con_frank, 
times=100)

autoplot.microbenchmark(bencho_1core)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También probé en paralelo. En tu caso comentás que estás usando `parLapply`. La "lentitud" se podría atribuir a que `lapply` trabaja con listas y para aplicarla sobre una matriz tiene que procesar internamente muchos cambios de estructura, verificaciones de tipos, etc. Por eso intenté con `parApply`, que se supone copia el funcionamiento de `apply`. 
Al menos con los datos que probé y mi hardware modesto de 2 núcleos físicos hay una penalización fuerte de desempeño.

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2,type="SOCK")  #Creo un cluster con dos núcleos

bencho_2core <- microbenchmark(
  parApply(cl, test, 2, rank) -> con_rank_2c,
  parApply(cl, test, 2, data.table::frank) -> con_frank_2c, 
  times=100)

 stopCluster(cl)

 autoplot.microbenchmark(bencho_2core)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No hice el test junto porque se me complicaba crear el cluster dentro de la llamada de `microbechmark` y no quería afectar el desempeño en un hilo sobrecargando con el cluster. Pero deberían ser razonablemente comparables, sobre todo con tamaña diferencia.

Podría haber varias explicaciones:

- Con datos relativamente pequeños y una función muy rápida la sobrecarga de abrir varios hilos y reunir los resultados sobrepasa la "mejora" de trabajar en paralelo. Quizás con más columnas (o filas) la cosa cambie.
- Dos núcleos son poco para explotar paralelismo y necesito cambiar la compu. (Ryzen?)
- Armé mal el cluster y no elegí la función óptima para este problema. Sin embargo se supone que `parApply` es reemplazo directo de `apply`. Se podría probar otras funciones para paralelizar.
- Me llama la atención que en paralelo no solo sube la media y demás medidas, también sube mucho la dispersión. Esto empeora más las cosas.

En general y hablando de paralelismo en R hasta ahora he tenido buenos resultados aplicando soluciones en paralelo para funciones que demoran *mucho* en ejecutarse, por ejemplo, modelos complejos e intensivos en computación más que en memoria. En esos casos con dos núcleos reduzco el tiempo de ejecución a casi 50%. Con funciones sencillas nunca he tenido mejores resultados que usando funciones alternativas escritas directamente en c, como el caso de `frank`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por replicar el código. Sin embargo ya probé la función `frank` y en mi caso toma incluso más tiempo que `rank` y no sé a qué se deba. Aún así se que será útil en otros problema.